# Solved - In Power BI Desktop, is there a way to filter dataset based on filter passed via URL

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop

I have a report built in Power BI Desktop and published in Service that is a DirectQuery (and has to stay that way as the data needs to be refreshed on every change).  The table is quite large, and will continue to grow daily.  It is embedded into an app, and the app calls the Report via a URL and passes a UserId to filter the dataset so the user only sees the records related to him/her.

What I would like to do is filter the dataset coming in with that userId, as opposed to the entire dataset coming in, and then the report only showing the data for that UserId.  I know I can create a parameter in the Query Editor - but how do I assign the filter being passed via the URL to that parameter? Is that even possible, or the filter can only occur once the entire dataset is loaded?

Or maybe you have other ideas on how to make the report faster without Importing the data.  I'm open to ideas!

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Answer (score 2):

Aside of the complete agreement to what @davidebacci is saying, what comes to mind the speed up the report is

- that the PowerBI DQ set might be another hop introducing latency to the solution. If you have an app connecting to the db behind it, why not connect to it directly via a data gateway?

Given that that's not a possibility,

- can you shorten the amount of data immediately returned, say to the last 10 useful items - and ofcourse give a link to more data being returned, also politely warning the user this may take a little longer as it is more data which might sound logical to users, thus introducing a little slack to your solution.
- or aggregate the returned items into say days or another useful aggregate so you can split the data returned to save on latency/system resources?

Hoping to have helped!

Comment: Thank you for your response - you definitely gave me some items to think about and see how we can implement and improve the performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use query string parameters in the URL. More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-url-filters

Comment: Thank you - I am currently doing that.  This report is embedded in an app and the app is calling it using the URL and passing the UserId as a filter.  Is there a faster way to return the data, or this is the best practice?  Is it better to create a parameter in the Query Editor and then associate that UserId to the parameter, or passing it as a filter is the same thing?

Comment: What you're doing seems like the optimal solution to me given your architecture.